# Invertible harmonic oscillator

Tags: spectral-theory, harmonic-analysis, heat-equation, differential-operators

Let $T=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-x^2$ be the invertible harmonic oscillator.

What is the explicite  formula of $(T-i\xi)^{-1}$ with $\xi\in\Bbb{R}^*$.

Any help will be appreciated a lot of.

Comment: Don't assume that we know what you are talking about.

Comment: But why? for $H=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^2$, we can compute $(H-\mu)^{-1}$

Comment: What do you mean  by $\zeta^*(H)$

Comment: You mean the zeta function of the operator $H$.

Answer (score 2):

$T$ is a self-adjoint operator (provided you defined its domain in a sensible way), so yes, the operator $(T-i\mu)^{-1}$ exists for any $0\neq\mu\in\mathbb{R}$. But I don't think there is a nice formula for it other than simply writing "$(T-i\mu)^{-1}$": If $f=(T-i\mu)^{-1}g$, then $f$ is a solution of the differential equation
$$(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-x^2-i\mu)f(x)=g(x)$$
for example for $\mu=1$ this can be solved by [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-f%27%27(x)-x%5E2*f(x)-i*f(x)%3Dg(x)) (you can fix the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ by boundary conditions $f(\pm\infty)=0$). But its not a beautiful expression, so I doubt that this is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot of. But is I can find its explicit formula  in the litte

Comment: How I can make to result wolframalpha